# How to curve an already made curve?

Tags: bezier-curves

I created a curve, but now i need to take all the object and curve it again, like this:

[image]

Comment: does the *Curve* modifier work? Use a NURBS Circle.

Comment: how can i put it/link it to my actual curve?

Comment: yes, how can i connect my curve to the other one? sorry if my english is bad, isnt my main language :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the powerful *Curve* modifier to do this. Make a curve to use as the factor, name it something you can remember, and then select the curve you want to bend and go to modifiers and add a *Curve* modifier. You then will need to select the name of the curve you want to use as the factor, like this:

[image]

Now your curve should conform to the shape of the circle, however it may look a little odd:

[image]

What you need to do is select the circle and scale it to the desired size, you should end up with something like this:

[image]